# How to make Titan Framework text field required

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Titan Framework with a custom plugin I wrote. There is a settings page that has a tab and on it there is a text field:

```
array(
    'name'    => 'Slug',
    'id'      => 'my_slug',
    'type'    => 'text',
    'default' => 'my-slug',
    'desc'    => 'The slug.',
),
```

This text field allows the user to specify a slug for the plugin's frontend UI. The problem is that a user can clear this field out to nothing and then save settings which results in an error.

I understand that I can trap this condition in the PHP code when this setting option is used. I also understand this could be done using jQuery to enforce a value being specified, but it would seem like there should be a best practice solution.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to ensure this field has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can definitely save it as empty and yes you can prevent that with JS. But because there is no "pre save" filter, one way to address this is to to the method you mentioned, add a `placeholder` attribute to the field to give the illusion of a value when empty (this is just for a better user experience).

```
array(
    'name'    => 'Slug',
    'id'      => 'my_slug',
    'type'    => 'text',
    'default' => 'my-slug',
    'desc'    => 'The slug.',
    'placeholder' => 'post',
),
```

Then check for `empty` when getting the value.

```
$slug = $titan->getOption( 'my_slug' );
if ( empty( $slug ) ) {
    $slug = 'post';
}
```

Comment: I think this is easy enough to explain in the field description that the setting defaults to `my-slug`. Thanks.